# Rails Default Scope Ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope, default-scope

I'm trying to add a default scope to a model that I have where I need it to first order asc by one attribute and then order ascending by a delegated attribute on another model.

I have this so far:

```
  delegate :name, :location_1, :location_2, :location_3, :location_4,
    to: :park,
    allow_nil: true,
    prefix: true

  default_scope order('coaster_sort ASC').order('park_name ASC')
```

I keep getting an error stating that park_name does not exist, (which is true as it's not on that model) but it is delegated.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do `joins` on the associated table in order to order by it.  I haven't tested this, but something like:

`default_scope joins(:other_model).order('coaster_sort ASC').order('<other_model>.park_name ASC')`

I haven't tested the above code, but I've done this before...  The `order` symbols may need to be adjusted for your code.

Comment: Ok, If I need to reverse the ordering to decending, where would I add that?

Comment: Then you would use strings:  `.order('coaster_sort DESC')`

Comment: It sort of works but the query being run is failing:   SELECT "coasters".* FROM "coasters" INNER JOIN "parks" ON "parks"."id" = "coasters"."park_id" ORDER BY coaster_sort, '---
:park: :name

Comment: Try just doing raw SQL strings instead of symbols.  I'll update my answer.